# How to initialize 2D array to false using ranged-based for loop

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently stuck trying to use a range base for loop to initialize my array.

What i have currently does it but its not utilizing C++ 11 Array in the constructor. The constructor is void and takes no parameters

```
//sets everything to flase
for (size_t rowCount = 0; rowCount < NROWS; ++rowCount) {
    for (size_t colCount = 0; colCount < NCOLS; ++colCount){
        m_Floor[rowCount][colCount] = STARTING_PEN_POSITION;
    }
}
```

Here is what I have so far to set everything to false (starting pen position)

```
for (auto const &row : m_Floor) {
    for (auto const &column : row) {
        //something = STARTING_PEN_POSITION;
    }
}
```

and this array is inside the header file

```
std::array <std::array <bool, NCOLS>, NROWS> m_Floor;
```

where NCOLS is a constant static of size_t with a value of 70

and NROWS is a constant static of size_t with a value of 22

Comment: Remove the `const` after `auto`..

Comment: just to make sure if i remove it then use the code `m_Floor[row][column] = STARTING_PEN_POSITION;` it doesn't work unless i'm using the syntax wrong for the for loop

Comment: You'd do `column = STARTING_PEN_POSITION;`, not `m_Floor[row][column] = STARTING_PEN_POSITION;`. Or more reasonably, you'd rename `column` to `cell`, to make it clear that it's a reference to a single cell in the matrix. Or for extra simplicity, you'd remove the inner loop, and just do `for (auto& row : m_Floor) { std::fill(std::begin(row), std::end(row), STARTING_PEN_POSITION); }`.

Comment: I see thanks for helping out I was having trouble with the syntax for quite a while and I didn't know it would be something as calling the cell instead of doing something like m_Floor

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear on the meaning of your question so I will post the answers to the two possible questions I can see above.  The first being why your intialization in a range based for loop is not working.  As pointed out in the comments, you need to remove the const.  Reference the following compilable program for that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using std::array;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {

    array<array<int, 10>, 10> two_dimensional_array;
    for (auto& arr : two_dimensional_array) {
        for (auto& ele : arr) {
            ele = 0;
        }
    }

    // print all the values
    for (auto arr : two_dimensional_array) {
        for (auto ele : arr) {
            cout << ele << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The other question I inferred is that you want a nice way to initialize your 2 dimensional array in one line in the constructor.  You can achieve this with `vector`s.  They are dynamic arrays which are usually super optimized.  You can use the `vector` constructor to initialize objects.  Reference the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main() {

    vector<vector<int>> two_dimensional_vector (10, vector<int> (10, 5));
    for (auto& vec : two_dimensional_vector) {
        for (auto ele : vec) {
            cout << ele << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have not used the [uniform initialization syntax](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language#uniform-init) because this is one of the places where it can be confusing